# $1+i$ is a prime element of ring of Gaussian integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, gaussian-integers

I want to prove that $1+i$ is a prime element of ring of Gaussian integers $Z[i]$. I started off with saying that if $1+i$ is prime then $1+i|(a+bi)(c+di)$ implies $1+i|a+bi$ or $1+i|c+di$ for $a+bi,c+di$ in $Z[i]$.
Taking conjugate, we get

$1-i|(a-bi)(c-di)$

Next we get,

$2|(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$

Since $2$ is a prime in $Z$ hence $2|(a^2+b^2)$ or $2|(c^2+d^2)$. After this I am stuck. I do not know how to get $1+i|a+bi$ or $1+i|c+di$ from here. Please suggest.

Comment: Hint: What does $2\mid a^2+b^2$ tell you about the parity of $a,b$?  Can you see why $(a+bi)/(1+i)\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ as a result?  (similar for $c,d$ instead)

Comment: @user10354138 I do not have any idea about parity.

Comment: [Parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)) just means whether the integer is even or odd.  So if $2\mid a^2+b^2$, what can you say about the parity of $a^2,b^2$?  So what about parity of $a,b$?

Comment: Another approach: since $a^2$ and $b^2$ are $\geq 0$, then the number of possibilities is severely limited; if $a^2+b^2=2$ we must have either $a^2=2, b^2=0$, $a^2=1, b^2=1$ or $a^2=0, b^2=2$.

Comment: When you want to prove that $1+i$ is prime, it's a very bad idea to start off by saying, "if $1+i$ is prime, then...."

Comment: @Gerry Myerson That's  what I want to arrive at in the end. Otherwise I started off with the first part of the implication  only.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Why is $a^2+b^2=2$, it could be any even number.

Comment: If $1+i$ is composite, $1+i=(a+bi)(c+di)$, multiplying by the conjugate you get $2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$, so $a^2+b^2$ is one or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your way of phrasing your solution is not entirely correct. If you are trying to show that $z$ is prime, you should not start with "If $z$ is prime". However, your working is actually salvageable.

---

You showed that if $(1 + i) \mid (a + bi)(c + di)$, then that alone implies $2 \mid (a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)$.
(Without any assumption of $1 + i$ being prime. This is what I meant with "salvageable".)

WLOG, we have $2 \mid (a^2 + b^2)$. (We wish to show that $(1 + i) \mid (a + bi)$.)

Thus, either $a$ and $b$ are both even or both odd.

**Case 1.** $a$ and $b$ are even.
In this case, $2 \mid a$ and $2 \mid b$ and hence, $2 \mid (a + bi)$. Since $1 + i \mid 2$, you are done.

**Case 2.** $a$ and $b$ are odd.
Write $a = 2a' + 1$ and $b = 2b' + 1$ for integers $a', b'$.
Then, $$a + bi = 2(a' + b'i) + (1 + i).$$
Again, since $(1 + i) \mid 2$, it follows that $(1 + i) \mid a + bi$.